# at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) error

Tags: java

```
  private static int posNum() {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            int input = 0;
            boolean error;

            if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                input = scan.nextInt();
                error = input <= 0;
            } else {
    28          scan.next();
                error = true;
            }
            while (error) {
                System.out.print("Invalid input. Please reenter: ");
                if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    input = scan.nextInt();
                    error = input <= 0;
                } else {
                    scan.next();
                    error = true;
                }
            }
            scan.close();
            return input;

        }
```

So the second time I call this method its returning the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at q2.CylinderStats.posNum(CylinderStats.java:28)
    at q2.CylinderStats.main(CylinderStats.java:62)
```

The first call is `rad = posNum();` which runs fine and then secondis `height = posNum();` which doesn't allow a value to be entered before it goes to the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while calling `next` you should check if scanner has one.

```
 if(scan.hasNext())
 scan.next();
```

According to java doc of [Scanner#next](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)

> NoSuchElementException if no more tokens are available

You can change your method like below

```
private static int posNum(Scanner scan) {
    int input = 0;
    boolean error = false;
    if (scan.hasNext()) {
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            input = scan.nextInt();
            error = input <= 0;
        } else {
            scan.next();
            error = true;
        }
    }
    while (error) {
        System.out.print("Invalid input. Please reenter: ");
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            input = scan.nextInt();
            error = input <= 0;
        } else {
            if (scan.hasNext())
                scan.next();
            error = true;
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

And then call it like below

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = posNum(scan);
    System.out.println(i);
    int j = posNum(scan);
    System.out.println(j);
```

Comment: unfortunately then the first time I call it, it won't store the first input.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that it runs once and gives you trouble means it is not able to read anything from the stream.

From Java DOCs:

When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.

Which means it closes the System.in

So leaving the scanner opened will prevent the error the second time.

Remove `scan.close();` and your program should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
private double getDoubleValue(String messageText) {
        System.out.print(messageText);

        while (true) {
            if (scanner.hasNext() && scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                return scanner.nextDouble();
            }

            System.out.print(INVALID_VALUE_DESCRIPTION);
            scanner.next();
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).