# Trying to ask the user for input in another method

Tags: java, file, input

I'm trying to ask the user for an input in the "doDeposit" method and check if the ID entered matches one from the file, however I get the error "at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)" when trying to use the Scanner.

The file it my program reads from has the following data:

```
Brain Adams,51,B10000,3000.5,1
John Waterson,30,B10001,4000.34,0
John Key,61,B10002,56666600,2
Julia Roberts,28,B10003,454545,1,
Tom Cruise,27,B10004,340000000,1
Johnny Tom,54,B10005,230,0
Joe Haldeman,66,B10006,23055.5,0
Charles King,55,B10007,2400.5,0
James Thomson,44,B10008,330.5,0
Cameron Diaz,28,B10009,23000000.6,1
Barak Obama,84,B10010,2000000.4,2
Dustin Hoffman,37,B10011,23000000,1
Robin Williams,72,B10012,22000000.5,1
Russell Crowe,47,B10013,44000000.3,1
Kylie Minogue,28,B10014,10000000.3,1
Paul Keating,41,B10015,4000000.8,2
Lady Gaga,32,B10016,50000000,1
Helen Clark,502,B10017,400000,2
Mikhail Suzenski,32,B10018,0.0,0
Boris Yeltsin,21,B10019,10000000.5,2
```

My code:

```
    package assignment;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import static java.lang.System.out;

    public class Assignment
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    try
    {
        new 
    BankAccountApp("C:/Users/USER/workspace/assignment/data/AssignmentData");
}
    catch (IOException ioe)
{
        out.printf("Missing file: %sC:/Users/USER/workspace/assignment/data/AssignmentData? \n\n",
                new Assignment().getClass().getPackage().getName());
}
}
}
class BankAccountApp
{
    private List<BankAccount> accounts;
    public BankAccountApp(String filename) throws IOException
{
        readAccountData(filename);
        displayMenu();
        int opt = 0;
        try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in))
{
            while (true)
{
                out.print("\nSelect an option: ");
                opt = input.nextInt();// format exception if string
                if (opt < 0 || opt > 7)
                    out.println("Invalid. Must be 1 - 7 (or 0 for menu).");
                else
                    break;
}
}
        switch (opt)
{
        case 0: displayMenu(); break;
        case 1: doDeposit(); break;
        case 2: doWithdraw(); break;
        case 3: displayHighestBalanceAccount(); break;
        case 4: displayMostActiveAccount(); break;
        case 5: displayAllAccounts("C:/Users/USER/workspace/assignment/data/AssignmentData"); break;
        case 6:
{
    int total = getTotalTransactions(accounts);
    out.println("Total transactions: " + total);
    break;
}
case 7: farewell(); return;
}
}
    public void readAccountData(String fn) throws IOException
{
            accounts = new LinkedList<>();
            Path path = new File("C:/Users/USER/workspace/assignment/data/AssignmentData").toPath();
            List<String> content = Files.readAllLines(path);
            for(String line : content){
                String[] items = line.split(",");
                String name = items[0];
                int age = Integer.valueOf(items[1]);
                String accountID = items[2];
                double balance = Double.valueOf(items[3]);
                int accountType = Integer.valueOf(items[4]);
                BankAccount b = new BankAccount(name, age, accountID, balance, accountType);
                accounts.add(b);
            }
        }

    public void displayAllAccounts(String fn) throws IOException
{
        accounts = new LinkedList<BankAccount>();
        Path path = new File(fn).toPath();
        List<String> content = Files.readAllLines(path);
        for(String line : content){
            String[] items = line.split(",");
            String name = items[0];
            int age = Integer.valueOf(items[1]);
            String accountID = items[2];
            double balance = Double.valueOf(items[3]);
            int accountType = Integer.valueOf(items[4]);
            BankAccount b = new BankAccount(name, age, accountID, balance, accountType);
            accounts.add(b);
            out.printf("---All Bank Accounts---\n");
            out.println("Name: "+name);
            out.println("Age: "+age);
            out.println("Account ID: "+accountID);
            out.printf("Account Balance: %f",balance);
            out.println("\nAccount Type: "+accountType+"\n");
        }
        return;
}
    public void displayHighestBalanceAccount()
    {
        BankAccount mostMoney = accounts.get(3);
        for(BankAccount b : accounts){
            if(mostMoney.getbalance() < b.getbalance()){
                mostMoney = b;
            }
        }
        String name = mostMoney.getname();
        int age = mostMoney.getage();
        String accountID = mostMoney.getaccountID();
        double balance = mostMoney.getbalance();
        int accountType = mostMoney.accountType();
        out.printf("---Bank account with the highest balance---\n");
        out.println("Name: "+name);
        out.println("Age: "+age);
        out.println("Account ID: "+accountID);
        out.printf("Account Balance: %f",balance);
        out.println("\nAccount Type: "+accountType);
    }
    public void displayMostActiveAccount()
{

}
    public int getTotalTransactions(List<BankAccount> list)
{
    return 0;
}
    public void doDeposit()
{
        out.print("Enter an account ID for deposit: ");
}
    public void doWithdraw()
{
}
    public void farewell()
{
        out.println("Thanks for using the service. Bye!");
}
    public void displayMenu()
{
        out.println("*********************************");
        out.println("* Bank Account Operation Menu *");
        out.println("***********************************\n");
        out.println("0. Display Menu");
        out.println("1. Deposit");
        out.println("2. Withdraw");
        out.println("3. Display Highest Balance Account");
        out.println("4. Display Most Active Account");
        out.println("5. Display All Accounts");
        out.println("6. Display Total Number of Transactions");
        out.println("7. Exit");
}
}
class BankAccount1 extends Person1
{
    private String accountID;
    private double balance;
    private int accountType;
    public String getaccountID() {
        return accountID;
    }

    public void setaccountID(String accountID) {
        this.accountID = accountID;
    }

    public double getbalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setbalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int accountType() {
        return accountType;
    }

    public void setaccountType(int accountType) {
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }
    public BankAccount1(String name, int age, String accountID, double balance, int accountType)
    {
        super(name, age);
        this.accountID = accountID;
        this.balance = balance;
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }
}
class Person1 {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getage() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setage(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public Person1(String name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874791/at-java-util-scanner-throwforunknown-source-error

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code. I found two errors.

1. you have a BankAccount1 class and You refers to BankAccount. without "1".
2. You use a wrong path
   See your path is

   `C:/Users/USER/workspace/assignment/data/AssignmentData`

But Path should be like below

```
   C:\\Users\\Menuka\\IdeaProjects\\JavaTest\\src\\AssignmentData`
```

I'll post full code below.

https://gist.github.com/Menuka5/2af4d16dccbdf780d730fd8bf5ce4e56